# Web service not working in web player build Unity5

Tags: c#, web-services, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get product description from server using web service. This is working fine in unity editor but when i created web player build it's not working.

what should be the problem ? Why it is not working in web player build ?

this is the sample code i am trying :

```
public void product_detail()
{
    string url = "http://*****/api.php?method=get_product_detail&product_id=" + name + "";

    Debug.Log(url);
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest1(www));
}
IEnumerator WaitForRequest1(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
    // check for errors.
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW data: " + www.data);
        Processjson(www.data);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
private void Processjson(string jsonString)
{

    JsonData jsonvale = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonString);

    var vc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString,typeof(Rootobject)) as Rootobject;
    //string status = jsonString;
    p_deail = jsonvale["detail"].ToString();
    p_price = jsonvale["price"].ToString();


    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("P_detail",p_deail);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("P1_price",p_price);

    Component com = GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent("FirstPersonController") as MonoBehaviour;
    (com as MonoBehaviour).enabled = false;

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Product",prefab.name.ToString());
    GUIWindow.SetActive(true);
    GameObject clone = Instantiate (prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

    clone.AddComponent<zoomC>();
    clone.AddComponent<rotatC>();
    clone.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward*1.0f + Camera.main.transform.right*-0.5f + Camera.main.transform.up*-0.2f;

    clone.transform.rotation = new Quaternion( Camera.main.transform.rotation.x, Camera.main.transform.rotation.y, Camera.main.transform.rotation.z, Camera.main.transform.rotation.w );
    clone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);

}
```

Comment: Does Unity transpile C# into JavaScript?

Comment: possible but i don't know